# I have$('.class:first'), I want $(.class:fourth') using jquery

Tags: jquery

I can select the first item in the div using

```
$('.class:first')
```

Now since I will have random id values, and the class remains the same, I want to access the id of the fourth element, will it be something like this

```
$('.class:fourth')
```

using jQuery.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>$('.class:nth(4)')</strike>

UPDATE:

<strike>Actually it's `$('.class:nth-child(4)')`</strike>

UPDATE2:

The correct answer is given by @cletus with a great explanation of the differences between `nth-child` and `eq` selector:

```
$('.class:eq(3)')
```

Please mark his answer as correct.

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways of doing this. Firstly you can use the [`:eq(n)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) pseudo-element:

```
$(".class:eq(3)")...
```

`:eq(n)` is zero-based so `:eq(3)` is the fourth instance. You can also use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$(".class").eq(3)...
```

The correct answer is *not*:

```
$(".class:nth-child(4)")...
```

What's the difference? The last one finds all elements that have a class of "class" that are the fourth child of something. That could be zero or many elements.

Comment: `.eq(3)` should be used in preference to the selector version. `:eq` is not a standard CSS selector; it is a jQuery hack, which will force the selector to be evaluated using the (slow) JS Sizzle library instead of the (fast) built-in `querySelectorAll` method present in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do $("expr").eq(2) - detail [here](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)